# Local storage data no longer displays after refresh

Tags: javascript, local-storage

Every time I refresh the page the localstorage data does not display in "test-div". Any ideas why this might be? when I run localStorage from the console I can still see the data it just gets removed from "test-div" with every refresh.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.modal').modal();

   $(".btn-add-basket").click(function(){
  
    var parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
    var itemName= parent_id[0].querySelector("h4").innerText;
    var itemPrice = parent_id[0].querySelector("span").innerText;
    var itemImage= parent_id[0].querySelector("img").src;
    var testDiv = $(".test-div");
    
     var fullItem = {
       itemName: itemName,
       itemPrice: itemPrice,
       itemImage: itemImage
     };

  localStorage.setItem("my-items", JSON.stringify(fullItem));
  storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-items"));
  console.log(storedItems);
  $(".test-div").append(storedItems.itemName);
});

});
```

Comment: It's because you should read from the local storage once the page loads and immediately update your HTML.

Comment: I see, any suggestion on how I would go about that?

Answer (score 2):

Move localStorage.getItem on top

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.modal').modal();

  const storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-items"));
  $(".test-div").append(storedItems.itemName);

  $(".btn-add-basket").click(function () {

    var parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
    var itemName = parent_id[0].querySelector("h4").innerText;
    var itemPrice = parent_id[0].querySelector("span").innerText;
    var itemImage = parent_id[0].querySelector("img").src;
    var testDiv = $(".test-div");

    var fullItem = {
      itemName: itemName,
      itemPrice: itemPrice,
      itemImage: itemImage
    };

    localStorage.setItem("my-items", JSON.stringify(fullItem));
    $(".test-div").append(fullItem.itemName);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

$(".test-div").append(storedItems.itemName); is inside a click function.

If you (also) add it outside of the click it will display when the page loads. Or you can just add this above or below the click

```
if (localStorage.getItem(storedItems) !== null) {
   $(".test-div").append(storedItems.itemName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the top of of your ready function read from the storage and append the items, if they are there, to your test div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  const storedItems = localStorage.getItem("my-items");
  if (storedItems !== null) {
    const storedValues = JSON.parse(storedItems);
    $(".test-div").append(storedValues.itemName)
  }

  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not read the local storage content when the document is ready but only when you click on the button, try moving the last 3 lines after the click callback of the button like this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('.modal').modal();

 $(".btn-add-basket").click(function(){
  
    var parent_id = $(this).parent().parent().clone();
    var itemName= parent_id[0].querySelector("h4").innerText;
    var itemPrice = parent_id[0].querySelector("span").innerText;
    var itemImage= parent_id[0].querySelector("img").src;
    var testDiv = $(".test-div");
    
     var fullItem = {
       itemName: itemName,
       itemPrice: itemPrice,
       itemImage: itemImage
     };

  localStorage.setItem("my-items", JSON.stringify(fullItem));
  $(".test-div").append(fullItem.itemName);
});

  storedItems = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("my-items"));
  console.log(storedItems);
  if(storedItems) {
     $(".test-div").append(storedItems.itemName);
  }

});
```

When the document is ready, an handler will be attached to the button  on click and then it will read your local storage.

Comment: Now the test div won't be updated once the button is clicked.